# Tailwind css not detecting colors with arbitary values

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to change colors depending on the role of users , i am using useState hook here to update the class , the classnames are getting updated but the tailwind css is not able to detect the class and not changing the color

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const RoleSelector = () => {
  const roles = [
    'STUDENT',
    'INSTRUCTOR',
    'PARENT',
    'ADMINISTRATOR',
    'SERVICES',
    'COMMUNITY',
    'PUBLIC',
  ];

  const RoleColorMapper = {
    'STUDENT': '#b667aa',
    'INSTRUCTOR': '#4e90ca',
    'PARENT': '#689d52',
    'ADMINISTRATOR': '#caa646',
    'SERVICES': '#e13b47',
    'COMMUNITY': '#4cd1af',
    'PUBLIC': '#e06c1a',
  };

  const RoleColorMapperSelected = {
    'STUDENT': '#370a37',
    'INSTRUCTOR': '#112a40',
    'PARENT': '#112a0a',
    'ADMINISTRATOR': '#5a4308',
    'SERVICES': '#5a080e',
    'COMMUNITY': '#043b38',
    'PUBLIC': '#4f2100',
  };

  const [ userRole, changeUserRole ] = useState('STUDENT');

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
      {roles.map((r) => (
        <div
          key={r}
          className={`${
            r === userRole
              ? `bg-white rounded-l-lg bg-white shadow-md p-4`
              : `px-4 py-4 text-[${RoleColorMapperSelected[r]}]`
          } mt-4`}
        >
          <button
            className={`${
              r === userRole
                ? `text-[${RoleColorMapperSelected[r]}]`
                : `text-[${RoleColorMapper[r]}]`
            }`}
            onClick={() => changeUserRole(r)}
          >
            {r}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RoleSelector;
```

my ts.config.js looks like

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
   
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

for example the class text-[#112a40] doesnot getting detected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in tailwind you can't use dynamic class naming like `text-[${color}]`. because tailwind compiles its css, it looks up over all of your code and checks if a class name matches.